# Does a deleted flagged comment still get reviewed by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

I was just wondering if some user posts some comments I found rude or inappropriate and I flagged the comment just when it was deleted. If I check my flags (by flagging another comment) I find that the flag has been registered because one is missing.

So if the user has deleted his/her comment (which they thought was *indeed* rude), but it was flagged by me, wouldn't it paint them in a guilty light while the author sincerely regretted their comment. How do I retract my flag?

Are such flags received by the moderators? Or since the comment has been deleted, it vanishes? If it does vanish then why doesn't my flag count show me the full number instead of subtracting one?

Can't this system be used improperly by abusing someone and then deleting it? The person on the other end might feel hurt, but he/she has no way of preventing the OP from abusing someone else, right?

Comment: Not sure if you refer to me (as we did have some recent comment exchange), but I did not delete any comment of mine - I just flagged yours as abusive: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b09E1.png

Comment: Apart from policy and moderation, it sounds like you're confused about the flags themselves. Have you gone to your own profile, choosing "activity" and then clicked on the title "X helpful flags" where you can see what happened to them? If you pick one of the "pending" ones, it will take you to the post/comment where you can retract it by clicking flag again.

Comment: I have not mentioned desertnaut neither E_net4. This was just a casual query...

Comment: The answer below is correct. In the event that a moderator should do more than just remove the comment, one should flag a post instead of a comment. Flags on posts for moderator attention are not automatically handled.

Comment: This also means that if anyone tries to work around the system by posting comments and removing them afterwards, the user can still be reported with a post flag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, if any comment flag causes a comment to be auto-deleted (due to keywords present in the comment), the comment flag is marked helpful immediately and never enters the mod flag queue.

This is why custom comment flags should only be used to explain **why the flagged comment needs to be deleted**.

Comment: Then why is my `1` flag missing? It makes sense to give it back to me. Also, can't it be abused like I wrote in my question above? Also, comment was **deleted  by author** before it reached any program....

Comment: Because you used it to auto-delete the comment? Comment you flagged was not deleted by anyone other than yourself.

Comment: So it gets deleted automatically? I thought that first, it went through a moderator...

Comment: Yes, because the main outcome of comment flags are either: (1) comment gets deleted, or, (2) nothing happens. If comment is deleted, comment flag naturally gets marked helpful

Comment: @SamuelLiew you may want to clarify what happens with flagged comments deleted by author...

Comment: @alex that's probably answered in another question already