# I flagged a comment, and it got auto-deleted. Can I be sure that I chose the correct flag?

Tags: support, comment-flags, automatic-deletion

When I flag a comment that has already been flagged by a number of users, it disappears automatically, and my flag is marked as *helpful*.

Does the type of flag I raise matter to the system before deleting the comment and marking my flag as helpful?

I recently flagged a comment as *unfriendly or unkind*, and the auto-deletion took place, but I want to know if I raised the correct flag.

Would flagging a not-rude or abusive comment *(that has been flagged by other users)* as *rude or abusive* *(don't do this)* have the same effect?

A deleted comment suggested:

> If you flag a comment, the objective is to delete the comment. Comment deleted, mission accomplished. No need to spend any more time thinking about it.

Yes, but the knowledge that a *helpful* flag from auto-deletion does or does not ensure that you've flagged it correctly can influence how you flag in the future.

---

P.S. There seems to be an assumption that I used the *unfriendly or unkind* flag on "Thank you" comments. I would like to clarify that that's not the case:

I flagged a comment that said **"Why you steal my answer?"** *(referred to a more-detailed answer)* and **"Thanks for accepting the other answer rather than mine!"**.

<sub>Perhaps you could tell me if I chose the right flag? ^,^</sub>

Comment: @yivi What's wrong with trying to learn how the system works?

Comment: @khelwood How does that work? First the flag is marked helpful, then it's status is reverted by a moderator?

Comment: @khelwood I know, but this is auto-deletion.

Comment: yes, which is triggered by certain regex patterns, which is mentioned somewhere else. This question is most likely a dupe, at least if I can find the question

Comment: @Scratte I guess probably not for auto-deletions.

Comment: What does it matter if you flag stuff correctly as long as it gets the job done? When a "bad" or useless comment is gone, then the flag was right anyways. Beside that, the given flags for comments are extremly hard to get wrong IMO. Either something is rude, extremly rude, or no longer needed. When you get something wrong, then it's probably because the flag was wrong in general, not because of the chosen reason.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is here that isn't addressed elsewhere?

Comment: @Scratte Other than the spam and rude/abusive post flags, moderators *can not* change the state of a flag once the flag is marked helpful, declined, or disputed. For red flags (spam and rude/abusive post flags), moderators can change the state of all such flags on post to disputed.

Comment: @JonClements What do you mean?

Comment: *"What does it matter if you flag stuff correctly as long as it gets the job done?"* I've addressed this at the bottom of my post. *"When a "bad" or useless comment is gone, then the flag was right anyways."* No, flagging, for example, "Thank you" as unfriendly is wrong.

Comment: @AnnZen But when you flag "Thank you" as unfriendly it certainly won't delete the comment. This is also what I've said: If you get a flag wrong, in a sense that the comment is not removed or it is declined, then it's probably because the flag was wrong overall. I'm saying that getting a bad comment deleted not for the 100 % precise reason should be considered equally correct to the precise flag reason.

Comment: @akuzminykh *"But when you flag "Thank you" as unfriendly it certainly won't delete the comment."* Oh, it will, believe it or not.

Comment: @AnnZen That's probably because other people have flagged it as no longer needed ...

Comment: @akuzminykh Nope. I am *very* sure of what I'm saying.

Comment: @akuzminykh There's a regex that deletes certain comments after only one flag, because they're usually useless. "Thank you" comments fall into that category.

Comment: "*... if any comment flag causes a comment to be auto-deleted (due to keywords present in the comment), the comment flag is marked helpful immediately and never enters the mod flag queue.*" [(source)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396996/1364007)

Comment: @WaiHaLee Yeah, I know. That's not what this question is focusing on, though thanks!

Comment: @akuzminykh certain comments are deleted by a single flag, see eg [Why do comment flags sometimes take immediate effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266161/839601) and linked posts. Comments containing word "thanks" below certain length (20-30 chars iirc) are deleted like that, I experimented

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, the system doesn't care about the type of comment flag.

The objective of ***all*** comment flags is to indicate that the comment should be deleted. That's true regardless of the type of the flag, and it's true regardless of whether a human moderator evaluates the flag or the system handles it automatically. If the comment gets deleted, then your flag on the comment is marked helpful. On the other hand, if the comment is *not* deleted (e.g., because a moderator chose to retain it), then the flag is marked as declined. Fundamentally, a helpful flag means that the comment is deleted, whereas a declined flag means that the comment should not be deleted.

The corollary to this is if you don't think a comment should be deleted, then don't flag it—not with any type of flag.

**Still, please try to use the flags consistent with the intended reasons.** If you have questions about the meanings or intended uses of the standard comment flag reasons, please ask a new question about that. If a comment is not unfriendly or unkind, it's weird and probably inappropriate to raise that type of flag on it, even if it will ultimately just end up deleting the comment in the same way as a "no longer needed" flag.

I'm not going to let myself be boxed in by trying to declare a policy on the misuse of comment flags. The general policy applies here, as everywhere: if a moderator, in their judgment, catches you abusing the system, then you are subject to be warned and/or sanctioned. The occasional misclick or difference of opinion is *readily* distinguishable from a pattern of misuse.

Comment: Say a mod opens a user's profile to see their flags, and see a long row of "helpful" *unfriendly or unkind* flags that were from comments that initiates auto-deletion, like "Thank you" comments. Would the mod associate that with trolling/something worth taking action on, or would they think it's fine?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here, @AnnZen? Use the flags as they are labeled. A "thank you" comment is neither unfriendly nor unkind, so why would you flag it as such?

Comment: Me? I'm asking about how things are handled here.

Comment: Things are handled using common sense. I'm not going to tell you what a moderator will or won't pay attention to. If you appear to be misusing comment flags, then, yes, a moderator will probably care about that. Better to just not misuse them in the first place, don't you think?

Comment: You're right, which only makes this meta post more necessary, don't you think? :)

Comment: Err, no? I still don't know what the purpose of this Meta post is. Are the descriptions on the flag options confusing in some way? Perhaps I could clarify those.

Comment: I think @AnnZen is asking what will a mod do. Obviously they are using the wrong flag, which isn't good at all, even if the result is the same.

Comment: Challenging a mod with, "what would a mod do if I tried to abuse the system in this specific way" is an odd strategy. My confusion continues.

Comment: Challenging? I want a better understanding on how auto-deletion works. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Sorry if I ask dumb questions, I'll try to avoid them next time. I know you are very busy.

Comment: @10Rep Sorry for the confusion, but I did not say that someone used the flag on a "Thank you" comment; it was only an example.